# Loop iMacros through CSV file?

Tags: firefox, imacros

Here's what I currently have:

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.random-domain.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:new_message_form ATTR=ID:my_subject CONTENT=Custom<SP>Title
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:new_message_form ATTR=ID:my_message CONTENT=Hi,<BR><BR>This<SP>is<SP>a<SP>test<SP>message.<BR><BR>-<SP>Custom<SP>Name
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=ID:new_message_form ATTR=ID:reply_button
```

I'm using the iMacros for Firefox plugin.  I used to do a lot with iMacros years ago and can't remember how to do a couple of things properly.

1. I have a CSV file that just has one column and it's a list of URLs that should be rotated through (line-by-line) in the `URL GOTO=` field.
2. If the process times out when trying to go to a specific URL or during the submission process, it should timeout and restart the process after 10 seconds.
3. Is using `<SP>` required for blank spaces?  The plugin is adding it automatically, but I don't remember adding that when working with iMacros a few years ago...

Can anyone help me fix this in the script above?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually contains 3 columns in the csv, but will help avoid the  issue you mention.

with your .csv, I would recommend saving it from something other than Excel, as it tends to not play nicely with iMacros.  I've had good luck with UTF-8 encoded files saved out of Notepad++.

*an apostrophe at the beginning of a line denotes a comment.  There are explanations in line below.*

```
'This will have it continue if it times out
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
'Your ten second requirement
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 10
'prevents testing popup from showing
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

'Be sure that the csv has been saved as a UTF-8 encoded csv
SET !DATASOURCE Datasource.csv
'This dictates what row to start on
SET !LOOP 1
'this connects the loop counter to the row of the csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}


URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
'I usually put a short wait in before I try adding content, you can adjust this.
WAIT SECONDS=5
'By referencing them from a csv, you shouldn't need the <SP>
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:new_message_form ATTR=ID:my_subject CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:new_message_form ATTR=ID:my_message CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=ID:new_message_form ATTR=ID:reply_button
```

I usually add a validation step at the end as well, have iMacros produce a spreadsheet that confirms what has been updated.  Helpful if things time out.

Tack this on the end of the macro if you want to validate

```
WAIT SECONDS=5

ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:new_message_form ATTR=ID:my_subject EXTRACT=TXT
ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:new_message_form ATTR=ID:my_message EXTRACT=TXT

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=*.csv
```